# Use ng-show before ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible use ng-show or ng-hide before ng-repeat?
I'm tryng so:

```
<div ng-show="articolis">Non tieni sott'occhio alcun articolo!</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="articoli in articolis" class="item-button-right"><a href="#/app/guide/{{articoli.id_cont}}"><h2>{{articoli.titolo}}</h2></a>
    <button class="button button-assertive" on-tap="delArtPref({{articoli.id}})"> <i class="icon ion-trash-b"></i> </button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

but dont work!

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? the syntax looks correct...

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: I would show the div if "articolis" is not empty!

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to just let the property evaluate to a truthy expression, because an empty collection is truthy. Use this in your expression.

```
ng-show="articolis.length > 0"
```